# QGIS WMS using tile size restrictions

Tags: qgis, wms

When I add a WMS layer with a tile size restriction (2048 2048) the resulting WMS datasource in the QGIS project file is

```
<datasource>tiled=2048;2048,url=http://openmaps.gov.bc.ca/mapserver/base3</datasource>
```

This does not look to be a properly formed GetMap request, which I believe is resulting in the WMS server sending out a tiled WMS feed while ignoring the fact that the feed is transparent.  Using the transparency tools in layer properties results in the entire layer (features and background) becoming transparent.  If the tiled portion of the datasource is removed, the WMS feed displays correctly but does not print.   If you attempt to demo this, use the Layer group called "BASE_MAPPING_20K"

So is there a way to edit the GetMap request to be properly formatted with Width & Height & Transparent?

Comment: A data source is not a GetMap request.  The configuration of your server just sets what can be called as part of a GetMap request by some client.